Trying to add a column to a CSV Output
I need to add a Hostname to each line like below desired output.
first, I've added Hostname parameter inside function.
Param(
    [parameter(Mandatory=$True, ValueFromPipeline = $True, Position = 0)]
        [String[]]$ComputerName,
        [String[]]$Hostname,
        [switch]$Online
)

then , I have added Hostname variable inside PSCustomObject.
$pingable.add([PSCustomObject]@{'Hostname' =$Hostname;'Computer' = $Status.Address; 'Online' = $reachable})

Then,
Get-Pingables -ComputerName $servers.RecordData -Hostname $servers.Hostname

But I am getting an output like below.
 Hostname     Computer       Online
--------     --------       ------
{app1, app2} 10.xx.xx.xx  False
{app1, app2} 10.xx.xx.xx  False

My list.csv :
Hostname,RecordData
apps1,10.xx.xx.xx
apps2,10.xx.xx.xx

My desired output:
Hostname Computer        Online
-------- --------        ------
apps1    10.xx.xx.xx    True
apps2    10.xx.xx.xx    True

Script :
Function Get-Pingables {
    [cmdletbinding()]
    Param(
        [parameter(Mandatory=$True, ValueFromPipeline = $True, Position = 0)]
            [String[]]$ComputerName,
            [String[]]$Hostname,
            [switch]$Online
    )

    $pingable = [System.Collections.Generic.List[PSObject]]::new()
    $ComputerName | ForEach-Object {
        Set-Variable -Name "Status_$_" -Value (Test-Connection -ComputerName $_ -AsJob -Count 1)
    }

    Get-Variable "Status_*" -ValueOnly | ForEach-Object {
        $Status = Wait-Job $_ | Receive-Job 
        $reachable = $False
        $addr = ""
        
        if ($Status.ResponseTime -ne $null ) {
            $addr = $Status.Address
            $reachable = $True
            
        }

        $pingable.add([PSCustomObject]@{'Hostname' =$Hostname;'Computer' = $Status.Address; 'Online' = $reachable})
    }
    if ($Online) {
        Return $pingable | Where-Object { $_.Online } | Select-Object Computer
    } else {
        Return $pingable | Sort-Object -Descending -Property 'Online'
    }
}  

$servers = Import-Csv 'C:\temp\list.csv'

Get-Pingables $servers.RecordData | Export-Csv "c:\temp\output.csv" -NoTypeInformation


UPDATE1:
INPUT CSV :
HostName,RecordData
srv01,10.xx.xx.xx
srv02,10.xx.xx.xx

OUTPUT CSV:
"Hostname","Computer","Online"
"srv01",,"False"
"srv02",,"False"


I believe it would be better to have the function deal with the objects created by Import-Csv in order to keep the data together.
Now you send it the RecordData and the Hostname parts as separate arrays and inside the function, although you loop over the RecordData, you do not store the matching HostName to each object.
Basically, you would like your function to not only test the connection of each given machine, but at the end you want to either sort the results or output just a list of Computer objects, depending on the Online switch.
Try
Function Get-Pingables {
    [cmdletbinding()]
    Param(
        [parameter(Mandatory = $True, ValueFromPipeline = $True, Position = 0)]
        [object[]]$InputObject,
        [switch]$Online
    )
    process {
        $pingable = foreach ($machine in $InputObject) {
            Test-Connection -ComputerName $machine.RecordData -AsJob -Count 1 | 
            Get-Job | 
            Receive-Job -Wait | 
            Select-Object @{Name = 'Hostname'; Expression = {$machine.Hostname}},
                          @{Name = 'Computer'; Expression = {$_.Address}},
                          @{Name = 'Online'; Expression = {($_.StatusCode -eq 0)}}

        }
        if ($Online) {
            $pingable | Where-Object { $_.Online } | Select-Object Computer
        } 
        else {
            $pingable | Sort-Object -Descending -Property 'Online'
        }
    }
}

and use it like
$servers = Import-Csv -Path 'C:\temp\list.csv'
$servers | Get-Pingables | Export-Csv -Path 'c:\temp\output.csv' -NoTypeInformation


thanks but I am getting NULL value inside output CSV. I've updated my question. Both the computer column comes blank and the Online column returns incorrect information. Actually, those servers are up.

It would appear that the OP was using -AsJob to go parallel. It is not stated whether there are 7 or 7,000 hosts to be pinged.

@Arbelac Please try revised code

You might do better at having Get-Pingables dealing with one item at a time and use a Foreach to manage looping.
Also Best Practice ask for function names being singular, so use Get-Pingable
Examples:
$servers | ForEach-Object {
    Get-Pingable -ComputerName $_.RecordData -Hostname $_.Hostname
} | Export-Csv 'c:\temp\output.csv' -NoTypeInformation

or
$PingedCsv = foreach ($server in $servers) { 
    Get-Pingable -ComputerName $server.RecordData -Hostname $server.Hostname
} 
$PingedCsv | Export-Csv 'c:\temp\output.csv' -NoTypeInformation

or
$servers.foreach{
    Get-Pingable -ComputerName $_.RecordData -Hostname $_.Hostname
} | Export-Csv 'c:\temp\output.csv' -NoTypeInformation

If you NEED Get-Pringable to use array, just use a [Object[]]$Computer parameter and then deal with the properties inside the function.

"Hostname","Computer","Online"
"System.String[]","10.xx.xx.xx","False"
"System.String[]","10.xx.xx.xx.xx","False"   it returning system.String as Hostname.
